# Efficiently multiply OpenCL vector components?

Tags: opencl

I have a float8 vector type that I multiply the components of the vector using vector component addressing as follows ( note the variable v below isn't a constant in reality);

```
float8 v = (float8) (1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f);
float result = v.s0 * v.s1 * v.s2 * v.s3 * v.s4 * v.s5 * v.s6 * v.s7;
```

However this prevents my kernel from being vectorised when being compiled with Intel Code builder.

```
Device build started
Device build done
Kernel <test> was not vectorized
```

To over come this I started to create copies of the vector, masking the required components and multiplying them all together before trying to call the dot function however this all seemed rather inefficient and convoluted.

My question is therefore how can I multiply the components of my vector in a efficient vectorised manor?

Comment: If you only do one 8 to 1 product then it's difficult to vectorize. However if you want 128 to 1 or even greater, then it makes sense to divide the vector to 16 vector-8s and do 16 vector-8 product, then do 8 to 1.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by 8 to 1. I want to multiply each component of the float8 vector to get one float total if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

**My comment was wrong** as it is not a dot product you need in the result. It is simply a multiplication of 8 numbers. Parallel work data should be parallel, not in same container. If you want to multiply s0 s1 s2 ... s7 then you put them in consecutive vector variables

```
variable-1:  s0 p0 r0 q0 .... z0
variable-2:  s1 p1 r1 q1 .... z1

variable-8:  s7 p7 ....       z7
```

you can multiply those at SIMD speed and have 8 multiplications at a time using float8 type and continue as many times as you need, not just 8.

At each multiplication, you have responsibility to check for errors and overflows. But when hardware does 8 multiplications in a single instruction, which order do you want? You want them multiplied in increasing index order(serial,slow) or something like a pairwise multiplication on tree elements(less multiplications,faster,but give different results)? Order of operations may be important sometimes.

**If it is a gpu**, simply multiply items and instruction level parallelism + hyperthread engine of gpu achieves efficiency. **If it is cpu**, you should first check if your cpu supports **vertical multiplication instructions**(I doubt such thing exists), if not then you need to **multiply on array elements** not vector elements. This should be easier to vectorise as it is a **continuous data on main memory** since a cpu does not give explicit control on local memory.

Comment: Yes agreed that's what I started to do by creating copies of the original vector and masking in/out the required components in a vertical manor. I though this would be overkill but I'll need to measure to be sure. Maybe there's any easier way to switch my row vector to a column vector so that I can multiply all of the values in parallel?

Comment: If there is only 8 numbers, just multiply one by one. If there are thousands of such vectors needing vertical multiplication, then you should create 8 vectors that are thousands of elements and multiply them parallelly (horizontally) eachother.

Comment: Yes. I directly jumped and spring the trap, we  both were trapped I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for feed back guys. I'm still stumped :-( what ever I do to try and multiply the vector components prevents my kernel from being vectorised.

Comment: Then you should have each thread(compute thread) do more job such as 8 times the original. This should give it more vectorizasion freedom. Such as coputing 8 pixels instead of 1 per thread.